.Net Maui Android - How to load image from DCIM folder direct - without a picker
The user can create screenshots which are saved in "DCIM/" folder of the Android device. This is done in a plaform-specific class.
Later I want to load these images again to display them on screen.
How can I find a spcific image file in "DCIM/" folder?
How can I read the file to a Maui.Image?
This should be done without a file picker.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Have you tried Media picker?

As the documentation says: "Opens the media browser to select ...".
But the images should be loaded  'direct' - means without any dialog

Where is the image located? In fact, you can invoke platform code to call the android native code to read the image.

I created a new demo and achieved this function on my side, you can refer to the following code.
In my demo, I first created an image in folder storage/emulated/0/DCIM/image/testimage.png on my android emulator. Then we can load the image as follows:
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
#if ANDROID
          
        var dcimFolder = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim).Path;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("dcimFolder path = " + dcimFolder);//storage/emulated/0/DCIM     

        var imagepath = dcimFolder+"/image/testimage.png";

        Java.IO.File imgFile = new Java.IO.File(imagepath);
        if(imgFile.Exists()){
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("file exists.");
           byte[]  imageBytes =  File.ReadAllBytes(imagepath);

           var stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);

           mImg.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(()=> stream);
        }

#endif
    }

Update:

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Logzoon/20240610_135655.jpeg' is denied My
permissions on Android 33

You need to add the necessary permissions on file AndroidManifest.xml as follows and request runtime permissions.
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  />

And we also need to check and request runtime permissions. On Maui, we can use Permissions to achieve this.
You can refer to the code from my demo:
  private  async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         PermissionStatus  status = await  CheckAndRequestStoragePermission();

        if (status.Equals(PermissionStatus.Granted)) {
            readImageFromGallery();

        }
    }


    public async Task<PermissionStatus> CheckAndRequestStoragePermission()
    {
        PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();

        if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            return status;

        if (status == PermissionStatus.Denied && DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
        {
            // Prompt the user to turn on in settings
            // On iOS once a permission has been denied it may not be requested again from the application
            return status;
        }

        if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<Permissions.StorageRead>())
        {
            // Prompt the user with additional information as to why the permission is needed
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Needs permission","Tip","OK");
        }

        status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();

        return status;
    }


    public void readImageFromGallery() {

#if ANDROID
   
        var dcimFolder = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim).Path;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("dcimFolder path = " + dcimFolder);//storage/emulated/0/DCIM/image/image.png      

        var imagepath = dcimFolder+"/image/image.png";

        Java.IO.File imgFile = new Java.IO.File(imagepath);
        if(imgFile.Exists()){
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("---------->file exists.");
           byte[]  imageBytes =  File.ReadAllBytes(imagepath);

           var stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);

           mImg.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(()=> stream);
        }

#endif

    }

Note:
For more information, please check document: Permissions.

This looks very good, just what I need, thanks! I will try it next week

Waiting for your good news. :)

Hi @Haimo, have you tried the code above?

Unfortunately there is an exception when executing this line:
       byte[] imageBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imagepath);

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path  /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Logzoon/20240610_135655.jpeg' is denied
My permissions on Android 33 device
"android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
"android.permission.MANAGE_MEDIA"
"android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"
"android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"
"android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"
"android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"

Hi  @Haimo, you need to add the necessary permissions and also need to check and request runtime permission. Please check the updated part of my answer. :)

Now it works, thanks to your help! - Some confusion: Android lower than 33 needs runtime permission, 33 and higher do not. But CheckAndRequestStoragePermission() does not take into account, so I added these lines:              if (OperatingSystem.IsAndroidVersionAtLeast(33))
return PermissionStatus.Granted;

Congrats. For the permission on Maui, you can check document: Available permissions. From the document, we can find that ✔️ to indicate that the permission is supported and ❌ to indicate the permission isn't supported or isn't required.And If a permission is marked as ❌, it will always return Granted when checked or requested.

I use the methode of your sample above:  CheckAndRequestStoragePermission()   It works fine for versions up to Android 32. But with Android 33 it ALWAYS returns status DENIED!  Therefor I added these lines to your sample:     if (OperatingSystem.IsAndroidVersionAtLeast(33)) return PermissionStatus.Granted;

Congrats and thanks for your feedback. I also tested on android emulator (api 33) which works properly.  :)

What Android device are you using to test it?

I use a Samsung Galaxy S20 with Android 33

Sorry, I don't have a phone of this model. Have you tried on android emulator(pixel_5 api33)?

I decided not to store images in DCIM folder. It's not clear if it will be possible on all Android devices. Storage will be done in application subfolders only
